# Failure to use a WMS map as a map background in Geonode

Tags: python, wms, mapping, basemap, geonode

I try to add a new background to a map, so that user can choose from more options than the default ones.
The default map backgrounds are defined as follows:

```
DEFAULT_MS2_BACKGROUNDS = [
    {
        "type": "osm",
        "title": "Open Street Map",
        "name": "mapnik",
        "source": "osm",
        "group": "background",
        "visibility": True
    }, {
        "type": "tileprovider",
        "title": "OpenTopoMap",
        "provider": "OpenTopoMap",
        "name": "OpenTopoMap",
        "source": "OpenTopoMap",
        "group": "background",
        "visibility": False
    }, {
        "type": "wms",
        "title": "Sentinel-2 cloudless - https://s2maps.eu",
        "format": "image/jpeg",
        "id": "s2cloudless",
        "name": "s2cloudless:s2cloudless",
        "url": "https://maps.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wms",
        "group": "background",
        "thumbURL": "%sstatic/mapstorestyle/img/s2cloudless-s2cloudless.png" % SITEURL,
        "visibility": False
   }, {
        "source": "ol",
        "group": "background",
        "id": "none",
        "name": "empty",
        "title": "Empty Background",
        "type": "empty",
        "visibility": False,
        "args": ["Empty Background", {"visibility": False}]
   }
   # Custom XYZ Tile Provider
    # {
    #     "type": "tileprovider",
    #     "title": "Title",
    #     "provider": "custom", // or undefined
    #     "name": "Name",
    #     "group": "background",
    #     "visibility": false,
    #     "url": "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    #     "options": {
    #         "subdomains": [ "a", "b"]
    #     }
    # }
]
```

I wanted to add the following map background from WMS:

```
{
        "type": "wms",
        "title": "CUSTOM_TITLE",
        "format": "image/png",
        "id": "NEW_MAP_BACKGROUND",
        "name": "OrtoIlmakuva_2019",
        "url": "https://kartta.lahti.fi/teklaogcweb/wms.ashx",
        "group": "background",
        "visibility": False
   }
```

The new map background appears in the selection, but it is only white, empty background without the data from the source. There is no visible error.
What do I miss?

The activity in the network tab is as follows:
[image]
[image]

And the opening of the request link in a new tab results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
 <ServiceException>Unsupported WMS version</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what the request sent to the server is, you should be able to find this in the network tab of your browser debugger

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some pictures showing the requests send to the server. Hope it helps to find a solution.

Comment: please always use text not pictures - next what is the response when you open that link in a new tab?

Comment: Actually that is a very good pointer, but what does that mean in practice? Does it mean that Geonode supports only the newest version (1.3.0) of WMS?


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
 <ServiceException>Unsupported WMS version</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>

Comment: that response comes from the remote WMS - so probably

Comment: Well the remote service doesn't support WMS version 1.3.0 so probably